# thermal pad on ssd nvme

Tags: ssd, nvme, thermal-paste

I buy a SSD Samsung 970 EVO PLUS M.2 2 To.

Do I have to remove the sticker (marked in red on the attached picture) before applying the thermal PAD ?

[image]

Comment: The sticker is on a heat spreader. Why do you need additional cooling, with a thermal pad?

Comment: @spikey_richie modern fast SSDs work well in well ventilated cases, but under **very** heavy load can still generate enough heat that their controller/flash goes into thermal throttling and slow down by some amount. In a constrained case or under almost permanent heavy load a heatsink can help a lot. In the PS5 they basically state you *must* have an SSD with a heatsink to ensure good performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some heat is generated by an SSD it is nowhere near as significant as that generated by the CPU.

The sticker will slightly reduce the effectiveness of the thermal pad and heatsink, but will not stop them from doing a job that is far better than having no heatsink at all.

You can leave the label if you want, or you can remove it. There is unlikely to be a large enough difference that you would notice.

A CPU is different in that it generates a massive amount of heat, comparatively speaking, and absolutely *needs* it all removed straight away. An SSD generates *some* heat, but will operate almost perfectly without it. The reason for a heatsink on an SSD is to help when it is under very heavy loads, it is not an absolute necessity so having it ever so slightly worse by leaving the label is not going to be a deal breaker.

Comment: I finally kept the sticker. Some forums report that manufacturers (in case of warranty return) do not appreciate that the sticker is removed.